# Need normal distribution for kappa Fleiss and ICC (2, 1)?

Tags: normal-distribution, ordinal-data, agreement-statistics

I'm analysing a study of 4 raters and 34 subjects. I'm looking at the inter rater reliability.
For the ordinal results, I did a weighted kappa of Fleiss and for the other continuous results I calculated an ICC (2,1).

My question is if the data has to follow a normal distribution to be able to use the Kappa of Fleiss and the ICC (2, 1) correctly?

Comment: Kappa is a measure of inter-rater reliability. How could such data be normally distributed? They are discrete, usually with a quite small number of categories.

Comment: What about the ICC and the interpretation of the f test

Answer (score 4):

The Kappa statistics have to do with level of agreement in contingency tables and there is no normal distribution involved.  The same is true for intra class correlation.